# Wiki with offline support

Tags: gratis, wiki

I am looking for a wiki software with the following features:

- Offline support (i.e. that I can edit them on my laptop when I am offline and push the changes later)
- LaTeX (mathjax) support
- mobile (smartphone/tablet) friendly
- password protectable
- Optional WYSIWYG interface
- video support
- it should be free software (as in "free beer": gratis)
- search function
- revision history

Nice to have:

- tags
- free as in "free speech" (open-source)

With offline I just mean that I can have a copy of the wiki on my laptop (running on a local apache server) and be able to easily synchronize this with the wiki on the server. It should be free in the sense of "free beer". However free in the sense of "free speech" would be nice too.

Answer (score 3):

[DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) might be the solution for you and fits almost all your requirements:

1. [Sync Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:sync) to sync two DokuWikis.
2. [Mathjax Plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:mathjax) and other LaTeX plugins.
3. Most templates are responsive, e.g. [dokuwiki template](https://www.dokuwiki.org/template:dokuwiki) or [bootstrap3 template](https://www.dokuwiki.org/template:bootstrap3)
4. Offers [ACL](https://www.dokuwiki.org/acl) out of the box.
5. The closest you get to an WYSIWYG interface is probably the [CKGEdit](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:ckgedit), based on the [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)
6. Offers several plugins for video support e.g. [html5video](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:html5video)
7. It's Open Source, free as in free beer and free speech
8. Out of the box search plugin.
9. Out of the box revision history.
10. Namespaces out of the box, Tags with Plugins like [tag](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:tag) or [tagging](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:tagging).

Comment: DokuWiki is great and can run locally which you don't mention. What I'm not sure about is syncing the local instance with a server's instance. Since it is a flat file wiki, it should be feasible.

Comment: sorry, I thought that's clear since I mentioned that as the first point corresponding the first point in the request. What seems to be the problem with syncing the local and the server instance?

Comment: Somehow my brain simply missed the first item in the list. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks. The mobile friendly part also included of how to edit pages from a mobile device. In particular it should be easy to add pictures or videos. Maybe you could add some details about this point.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by adding pictures and videos? Uploading pictures and videos from your mobile device?